# Frama-C reports "invalid ghost in extern linkage specification" while loading .C files

Tags: frama-c

I am very new to Frama-C so perhaps I'm missing something obvious. As I try to load my project files (with some .C files among them) Frama-C reports the following error in the Console window and stops processing

```
  [kernel] FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_alloc_axiomatic.h:30: 
  invalid ghost in extern linkage specification:
  Location: between lines 30 and 45, before or at token: }
  28    #include "__fc_define_wchar_t.h"
  29    

  30    __BEGIN_DECLS
  31    
  32    /*@ ghost extern int __fc_heap_status __attribute__((FRAMA_C_MODEL)); */
  33    
  34    /*@ axiomatic dynamic_allocation {
  35      @   predicate is_allocable{L}(integer n) // Can a block of n bytes be allocated?
  36      @     reads __fc_heap_status;
  37      @   // The logic label L is not used, but it must be present because the
  38      @   // predicate depends on the memory state
  39      @   axiom never_allocable{L}:
  40      @     \forall integer i;
  41      @        i < 0 || i > __FC_SIZE_MAX ==> !is_allocable(i);
  42      @ }
  43    */
  44    
  45    __END_DECLS

  46    
  47    __POP_FC_STDLIB
```

It seems like the error is in Frama-C function spec library, maybe? I'm running Frama-C 20.0 (Calcium) on Ubuntu 19.10. Frama-C was installed via `opam`. Any insight into what this means would be very useful.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue with Frama-C 20.0 by launching it directly on `$FRAMA_C_SHARE/libc/__fc_alloc_axiomatic.h` or on a sample `test.c` file that includes `stdlib.h` (which in turn includes `__fc_alloc_axiomatic.h`), using as command line `frama-c -print test.c`. Could you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I traced the issue to the case of the file extension. It seems if the file extension is .C the file is interpreted as C++ (maybe) and including stdlib.h causes the fault. I haven't checked if other librareris cause an issue. If the extension is .c then the file is interpreted as plain C and the file loads normally. So minimal example is `#include<stdlib.h>` in file named `test.C`.

Comment: yes, the `.C` suffix is the problem here. and would warrant an edit of the question to explicitly mention this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl; dr:** don't use `.C` instead of `.c` as a suffix for a C file. In particular  [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html) recognizes by default that suffix as C++ instead of C source.

**longer answer with gory technical details:**
If you launch `frama-c` (without the very experimental [`frama-clang`](https://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html) plug-in) on a file named `file.C` (with an uppercase `C` as suffix), the preprocessor called by Frama-C will consider that it is handling a C++ source file. Technically, this means that it will define the standard `_cplusplus` macro, which in turn implies that the `__BEGIN_DECL` macro found in the `stdlib.h` file of Frama-C's libc will be expanded as if included in a C++ (i.e. as `extern "C" {`).

Had frama-clang been installed, it would have taken care of parsing the file, and should have succeeded. When this is not the case, the normal Frama-C parser is called. It has some limited support for handling `extern "C"` linkage specifications, as they can appear in the wild in some shared C/C++ headers, even though strictly speaking this is not standard C, but not all constructions are handled in this context.

Comment: The error message wasn't very helpful. It would be nice if it could at list hint that there was a potential language mismatch.